# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - C++ Compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, compiler-optimization

We observe a strange case where in VS2015 Update3 compiler will omit part of the code for no obvious reason.

We found out that

- This happens in VS2015 Update3 (Help|About says 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, cl.exe version 19.00.24215.1)
- This doesn't happen in VS2015 Update2 (Help|About says 14.0.25123.00 Update 2, cl.exe version 19.00.23918)
- This happens only when optimization is turned on (for example, in default Release configuration)
- Happens in both x86 and x64
- Happens when code snippet is inserted into brand new "Win32 Console Application" (I mean, no fancy commandline options required)

We managed to minimize the culprit code to this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _tmain(int, _TCHAR*[])
{
    volatile int someVar = 1;

    const int indexOffset = someVar ? 0 : 1;    // Loop omitted
    // const int indexOffset = !someVar;        // Loop omitted
    // const int indexOffset = 0;               // Good
    // const int indexOffset = 1;               // Good
    // const int indexOffset = someVar;         // Good
    // const int indexOffset = someVar + 1;     // Good

    for (int i = 1 - indexOffset; i < 2 - indexOffset; ++i)
    {
        printf("Test passed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the lines that say "Loop omitted", the entire loop body is omitted by compiler. Why? To my knowledge, there is no undefined behavior involved.

---

Disassembly for the first "Loop omitted":

```
int _tmain(int, _TCHAR*[])
{
01151010  push        ebp  
01151011  mov         ebp,esp  
01151013  push        ecx  
    volatile int someVar = 1;
01151014  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],1  

    const int indexOffset = someVar ? 0 : 1;    // Loop omitted
0115101B  mov         eax,dword ptr [someVar]  
    // const int indexOffset = !someVar;        // Loop omitted
    // const int indexOffset = 0;               // Good
    // const int indexOffset = 1;               // Good
    // const int indexOffset = someVar;         // Good
    // const int indexOffset = someVar + 1;     // Good

    for (int i = 1 - indexOffset; i < 2 - indexOffset; ++i)
    {
        printf("Test passed\n");
    }

    system("pause");
0115101E  push        offset string "pause" (011520F8h)  
01151023  call        dword ptr [__imp__system (0115205Ch)]  
01151029  add         esp,4  
    return 0;
0115102C  xor         eax,eax  
}
0115102E  mov         esp,ebp  
01151030  pop         ebp  
01151031  ret
```

---

Test project: http://dropmefiles.com/S7mwT

---

Try it online!

- Go to http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/
- Put sample code to the editor
- Put `/O2` to `Additional compiler flags`
- Check `Run executable after compilation`

---

Bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71906/compiler-optimization-code-generation-bug.html

Comment: Could you give the command-line for compiling the code? I'd like to try in the latest MSVC version. That said, it definitely seems like a bug. You also seem to be missing includes.

Comment: "Does not work" means that the message is not printed, or that the breakpoint is not firing? FWIW, what is the `main` assembler code for the first "Does not work" situation?

Comment: You have some includes missing. `tchar.h`, `windows.h` and `cstdio`. It's definitely a compiler bug - it works with MSVC x64 19.10.25019 (VS15 RTM) and 19.11.25325 (VS15.3 Preview). You should upgrade your compiler - MSVC 19.0 is unsupported.

Comment: @Codeguard -- You are looking at the version of Visual Studio itself, not the compiler version.  To get the compiler version, enter `cl /?` at the command line.

Comment: I posted the MSVC - Microsoft Visual C/C++ compiler version. The compiler and IDE aren't the same - they ship separately starting from VS15 (aka Visual Studio 2017). You can find the compiler version by opening the VS developer command and running `cl` (the compiler). There's also the linker version from `link`.

Comment: The versions posted by @tambre are of the actual compiler (`cl.exe`) instead of the version of the IDE.  This kind of information is more important going forward since projects in newer versions of VS can use compiler  toolchains from other VS versions.

Comment: If you want to see the compiler toolchain version in the IDE's build output change the `C/C++ | General | Suppress Startup Banner` project property to "No".

Comment: I think it's a compiler bug. I can reproduce it with VS 2015 (19.00.24215.1) and VS 2017 (19.10.25019), both 64 bit.

Comment: @manni66 I can't reproduce it with cl 19.10.25019 64-bit. It also doesn't happen on the [official online MSVC compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), which includes the latest internal revision, that's not even available in the preview yet (make sure to check "Run executable after compilation").

Comment: @tambre what compiler switches did you use? I compiled with  cl /EHsc /Ox

Comment: Actually disregard that. @Codeguard initially said in the comments no command-line options are required, so I didn't use any. Using `/O2` reproduces the bug.

Comment: @manni66 Just as a side-note, `/Ox` is old/legacy and shouldn't be used anymore. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/5mgyf2/passing_functions_to_functions/dd9svic/)

Comment: I'm going to open a bug report on their site, if you don't mind. I'll be back with a link to the report in a bit.

Comment: I intended to do it myself once it's clear I'm not missing something stupid.

Comment: BTW: you don't use volatile for thread synchonization, do you?

Comment: volatile serves the purpose of minimal reproducible example. The original code that cased problem for us has nothing in common with the sample code.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug, but I'm curious to see if the behavior changes when `someVar` is not `volatile`

Comment: @AndyG works fine without volatile.

Comment: So many people claim to have found a compiler bug when it's really a bug in their own code. So refreshing to see one that probably *is* a compiler bug!

Comment: Edits: Added "try it online" section

Comment: [I have reported the bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71906/compiler-optimization-code-generation-bug.html). Feel free to upvote it to get it fixed faster.

Comment: @Codeguard You might want to attach [the bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71906/compiler-optimization-code-generation-bug.html) to the question, so there are no duplicate reports.

Comment: @tambre Why not giving topic starter opportunity to report discovered rare bug? He explicitly stated intention to do that, so jumping into and reporting the problem without even giving credits to author doesn't look nice.

Comment: @nnovich-OK The bug report pointed back to this thread. The topic starter reported the bug anyways and already got an answer, so I deleted my bug report.

Comment: @tambre Initially the bug report wasn't pointing back until another user posted the link. I'm happy, that author got his credits, but this doesn't justify your actions.

Comment: @nnovich-OK I personally don't really care who opens the bug report, as long as the bug report is public, so others can participate, and incase of the bug being noteworthy (ie. security bug, a *very* weird bug, funny bug, etc) , the original finder being mentioned. I don't really consider compiler bugs that noteworthy anymore, as I've encountered and reported a little too many of them recently (in MSVC) and since most of them are small "oopsie"s.

Comment: @tambre I see your point. If you don't really care, then next time give opportunity to people who might (or might not) care and only then intervene. Mentioning original finder is always honored at least to appreciate his work.

Comment: One can see this clearly at Matt Godbolt's website. Check this out:
https://godbolt.org/g/UhxcRr

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug. Specifically, it's a bug in the new SSA optimizer introduced in VS2015 Update 3. [The undocumented command line option `-d2SSAOptimizer-` tells the compiler backend to use the old optimizer instead, which causes the bug to not manifest](https://godbolt.org/g/6C2Kj4).

FYI, you can minimize your repro to:

```
int main()
{
    volatile int someVar = 1;

    const int indexOffset = someVar ? 0 : 1;

    for (int i = 1 - indexOffset; i < 2 - indexOffset; ++i)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

which will help the compiler developers localize the problem more quickly.

---

Addition from **Codeguard** (I decided that **Casey**'s answer should be THE answer):
I have received reply from Microsoft (Gratian Lup, author of blog post [Introducing a new, advanced Visual C++ code optimizer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/05/04/new-code-optimizer/)):

> Yes, this is indeed a bug in the SSA Optimizer itself - usually most
>   bugs reported as being in the new optimizer are in other parts,
>   sometimes exposed now after 20 years.
>
> It's in a small opt. that tries to remove a comparison looking like (a
>   - Const1) CMP (a - Const2), if there is no overflow. The issue is that your code has (1 - indexOffset) CMP (2 - indexOffset) and subtraction
>   is not commutative, of course - but the optimizer code disregards that
>   and handles (1 - indexOffset) as if it's (indexOffset - 1).
>
> A fix for this issue will be released in the next larger update for
>   VS2017. Until then, disabling the SSA Optimizer would be a decent
>   workaround. Disabling optimizations for only this function may be a
>   better approach if it doesn't slow down things too much. This can be
>   done with #pragma optimize("", off): 
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

Comment: I believe compiler developer guys will eventually figure how to minimize further themselves... :)

Comment: Wow - I'm amazed that you got such a detailed answer from the MS Dev so quickly.  Nice question, great answer from @Casey and nice response from MS.